# SVG Polygon using coordinate in px

Tags: svg, polygon, antialiasing, clip-path

I want to use px on my svg polygon, something like:

```
<polygon fill="white" points="0,0 10px,0 10px,10px 0,100 100,100 100,0"/>
```

But it doesn't work, I tried to do with clip-path in CSS but it's look like a anti-aliasing thing:

[image]

Comment: omit the px, all the numbers in a polygon are interpreted as px anyway and units are invalid.

Comment: @RobertLongson Well yes, but I want to box have 100%, isn't that a problem?

Comment: Use a viewBox on an svg element to do that.